# Web приложение на Spring

Tags: java, spring, mustache

Пытаюсь создать web приложение на Spring, по урокам из ютуба
в нем есть такой файл greeting.mustache:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello, user</div>
<a href="/main">Main page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

когда его создавал, по первому уроку, все было ОК. Во втором уроке его не использовали. А теперь он снова  понадобился. Вот только теперь IDEA ругается в нем на строку:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

не нравится Content-Type.
в чем может быть проблема?
зависимости mustache на месте.
Причем, если создать такой же файл, но с расширением html, то все ОК, ругается только если расширение mustache.

Comment: А плагин для mustache у вас установлен?

Comment: плагина не было, но ошибка ушла когда записал вот так: http-equiv="content-type", хотя сама IDEA изначально предложила запись с больших букв

Answer (score 1):

ошибка ушла когда записал вот так: http-equiv="content-type"